# Derivative of order statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

--For further background into the question, one can refer to equations
 2.3 and 2.6 (page 1275 of [[0]](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/BetterThanMAD.pdf))--

Define:

$$g_G(x)=\mbox{med}_Y|x-Y|$$

where $X$ and $Y$ are independent stochastic variables with distribution function $G$;

In the above cited paper, the authors derive a closed form expression for $g_G'(x)$ when $G=\Phi$.

my questions is: How does it come about that when $G=\Phi$ and $x=q$: $$g_G'(x)=\frac{\phi(x-c^{-1})-\phi(x+c^{-1})}{\phi(x+c^{-1})+\phi(x-c^{-1})}$$ 
where $c^{-1}=\mbox{med}_X g_{\Phi}(X)$. That part is not clear to me.

reference:

- [0]:Rousseeuw, Peter J.; Croux, Christophe (December 1993),
  "Alternatives to the Median Absolute Deviation", Journal of the
  American Statistical Association (American Statistical Association)
  88 (424): 1273–1283, doi:10.2307/2291267

Comment: I have spent ~20 minutes on your question (before someone answered). I would never have found because you have not mentionned that the equality holds for $x=q$ and not for all $x$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I apologize for the confusion. Meanwhile I have corrected the oversight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the PDF and CDF of the standard Gaussian; that is,
\begin{equation}
\phi(x) = \Phi^\prime (x).
\end{equation}
To obtain $g_{\Phi}(x) \equiv {\rm med}_{Y} |x-Y|$ (the CDF of $Y$ is $\Phi$), one should find a distance $a$ such that for exactly half of the members of the Gaussian distribution, the distance from $x$ is greater than $a$ (and of course smaller than $a$ for the other half). This condition amounts to
\begin{equation}
F(x,a) \equiv \Phi(x+a) - \Phi(x-a) = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
Solving this for $a$ gives $g_{\Phi}(x)$. Therefore obtaining $g_{\Phi}^{\prime}(x)$ boils down to differentiating the implicit function given above. That is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g_{\Phi}^{\prime}(x) &= - \frac{\partial F/\partial x}{\partial F/\partial a} = \frac{\phi(x-a)-\phi(x+a)}{\phi(x+a)+\phi(x-a)}\\
&=\frac{\phi(x-g_{\Phi}(x))-\phi(x+g_{\Phi}(x))}{\phi(x+g_{\Phi}(x))+\phi(x-g_{\Phi}(x))}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then, using the fact that $g_{\Phi}(q) = 1/c = {\rm med}_{X}g_{\Phi}(X)$, where $q$ is defined by $\Phi(q) = 3/4$, gives
\begin{equation}
g_{\Phi}^{\prime}(q) = \frac{\phi(q - c^{-1})-\phi(q + c^{-1})}{\phi(q + c^{-1})+\phi(q - c^{-1})}.
\end{equation}

**Update**: How do we know that ${\rm med}_{X}g_{\Phi}(X) = g_{\Phi}(q)$?

Claim: $g_{\Phi}(x)$ is an even function that monotonically decreases as a function of $|x|$.

That this function is even follows from its definition (as an implicit function) given above and the fact that $\Phi(-x) = 1 - \Phi(x)$. It monotonically decreases in $|x|$ because
\begin{equation}
g_{\Phi}^{\prime}(x) \ \Bigg\{\begin{array}{ccc} >0 \ (x>0)\\=0\ (x=0)\\<0\ (x<0)\end{array}.
\end{equation}
One can see this from the expression for $g_{\Phi}^{\prime}(x)$ and the shape of the Gaussian function $\phi$. More rigorously, one should be able to deduce this fact from the following considerations:

1. $\phi(x) = \phi(-x)$.
2. $\phi(x)$ monotonically decreases in $|x|$.
3. $a = g_{\Phi}(x)>0$.

Then, the value of $x$ giving the median of $g_{\Phi}(x)$, which we denote as $q$, is where exactly half of the members of the Gaussian distribution falls within $|q|$. Hence  $\Phi(q) = 1/4$ or $3/4$. Evaluating $g_{\Phi}$ at either of the two values (they only differ by their signs, and $g_{\Phi}$ is even) would give ${\rm med}_{X}g_{\Phi}(X)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I was wondering, could you also recommend a graduate level book with more background on derivatives of order statistics?

Comment: @user603 Sorry. I don't really come from statistics background and don't know about books in this field. I found that you accepted my answer and then decided to revoke your decision. Did you want more explanation on why $g_{\Phi}(q) = 1/c$? In that case, I can update my answer.

Comment: :yes that would be great! –

Comment: @user603 I updated my answer. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: I don't understand why/how you are replacing $g_\Phi(x)$ with $g_\Phi(q)$ in the expression of $g'_\Phi(x)$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent The formula OP quoted is supposed to hold only at x=q. You can check that from the paper that is referenced.

Comment: Oh! The question should be edited then !